# Load xml malformed with simplexml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I've got a malformed xml file, basically it have ampersan(&) inside the tags and they are not escaped...

This is the code i'm using for loading the xml.

```
$archivo = "tarifa_mayorista.xml";
echo "Reading file<br>";
if (file_exists($archivo)) {
  $articulos = simplexml_load_file($archivo); 
  if($articulos){
    foreach ($articulos->Categoria as $rs) { 
        $categoria = (string) $rs->TxCategoria;
        $subCat = (string) $rs->SubCategoria[0]->TxSubCategoria;
        $cod = (string) $rs->SubCategoria[0]->SubCategoria2[0]->PartNumber;
        $stock = (string) $rs->SubCategoria[0]->SubCategoria2[0]->Stock;                
        $precio = (string) $rs->SubCategoria[0]->SubCategoria2[0]->Precio;
        $fabricante = (string) $rs->SubCategoria[0]->SubCategoria2[0]->Fabricante;  
        $ean = (string) $rs->SubCategoria[0]->SubCategoria2[0]->EAN;  
        $descripcion = (string) $rs->SubCategoria[0]->SubCategoria2[0]->Descripcion;
        $canon = (string) $rs->SubCategoria[0]->SubCategoria2[0]->Canon;
        $desc = mysql_real_escape_string($descripcion);     
        $sql2="insert into `activadosmil` 
               set  cod='".trim($cod)."', stock='".trim($stock)."', precio='".trim($precio)."', categoria='".$categoria."', 
               subcategoria='".$subCat."', descripcion='".$desc."', ean='".trim($ean)."', canon='".trim($precio)."', fabricante='".trim($fabricante)."'"; 
        mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error()."<hr>".$sql2); 
    }       
  } else echo "<br>Invalid XML sintaxis";
} else echo "<br>Error opening ".$archivo;
```

/* SAMPLE XML CODE */

```
<Categoria>
    <TxCategoria>ALMACENAMIENTO</TxCategoria>
    <SubCategoria>
        <TxSubCategoria>CARCASAS DISCO DURO</TxSubCategoria>
            <SubCategoria2>
                <TxSubCategoria2>2,5"</TxSubCategoria2>
                <PartNumber>5VECTRIXALU3,5</PartNumber>
                <Fabricante>TACENS</Fabricante>
                <EAN>4710700954461</EAN>
                <Descripcion>MONITOR ASUS LED&PIP 27 VE278Q</Descripcion>
                <Precio>       12.37</Precio>
                <Stock>        0</Stock>
                <Canon>      0.00</Canon>
            </SubCategoria2>
    </SubCategoria>
</Categoria>
```

Is there any way to load the xml malformed file with simplexml? Or escape the characteres from tags?

Thank you guys in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a naive solution that would work if your issue with ampersands is as naive as your question presents it.

You could first get the file contents as a string:

```
$contents = file_get_contents($archivo);
```

Then, you could run a str_replace to replace all occurrences of `&` with `&amp;`

```
$contents = str_replace('&', '&amp;', $contents);
```

Now, load the escaped string into your simplexml:

```
$articulos = simplexml_load_string($contents);
```

Comment: Yes, my problem was as naive as my questions sounds :p
Thank you.